# Structure causing program to crash

Tags: c, file-io, structure, readfile, file-pointer

```
int get_name()
{
    char cName[] = "hello";
    int iCode, i = 0;
    struct sign_in items[6];//array of six structure variables

    Fpointin =fopen("namepass.txt","r");

    if (Fpointin == NULL)
    {
        printf ("File does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            fscanf(Fpointin,"%s %d",items[i].name,items[i].password);//read all values from the file into th structure
        }
        printf("Here is the sign_in structure\n");//print the entirety of the sign_in structure
        for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            printf("name: %s\ncode: %d\n\n", items[i].name, items[i].password);
        }
    }
    fclose(Fpointin);
}
```

Hey all. So I've got this section of code from a project and it crashes whenever I try to run it. I'm trying to read names and their respective pass codes from a file to a structure and its not working. In the `fscanf` line I had the `%s %d` identifiers swapped and it ran but it printed random stuff that wasn't even close what was in the file. Any ideas?

---

[update from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760161/structure-causing-program-to-crash#comment61100147_36760161):]

```
struct sign_in
{ 
  int password; //The password for each player 
  char name[]; //Name of the people who can sign in
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(Fpointin,"%s %d",items[i].name,items[i].password);` I'm guessing that password is a string. If so, you need to use `"%s %s"` for the format string.

Comment: Post `struct sign_in` definition

Comment: How do I post code in the comments section?

Comment: Edit your answer please

Comment: Also your `fclose` may cause segfault if `fopen` will return `NULL`. You can add `return` to your `if` statement and remove `else` block for example

Comment: `struct sign_in{
    int password;//The password for each player
    char name[];//Name of the people who can sign in`

Comment: that last comment should have been entered as additional text to the question itself.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' format specifier, always include a 'max length' modifier (that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer) so the input cannot overrun the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the code must allocate memory for the `.name[]` field, not just a place holder.  Suggest something like: `char name[30];`  Note: then in the call to `fscanf()` use `29` as the 'max length' specifier.  Note: passwords are normally not an `int` but rather a string.   So your `struct sign_in` needs a bit of modification, as does the posted code

Comment: when asking a question like: `why does my code not work?` always post the actual input, the actual output, the expected output AND code that cleanly compiles, so we can setup and run the application in the process of debugging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**,you should not use `char name[]` in your structure. Because array should declear it's memory size before you use it.

So, you can change `char name[]` to:

1. `char *name` : That you have to allocate a memory size for it. check my code below.
2. `char name[NAME_SIZE]`

**Second**, if you want to change the value inside another function you should pass its' memory address to it. for example:

**Example 1:**  if you just pass the value but not address

```
void foo(int in)
{
    in = 5;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    int a = 10;
    foo(a);
    printf("after foo, a: %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**
`after foo, a: 10`

**Example 2:**  if you pass the memory address.

```
void foo(int *in)
{
    *in = 5;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    int a = 10;
    foo(&a);
    printf("after foo, a: %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**
`after foo, a: 5`

So, you have to pass `items[i].password`'s memory address to fscanf like:
`fscanf(Fpointin,"%s %d",items[i].name, &items[i].password);`

**Hence,your code should looks like:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sign_in {
    int password;//The password for each player
    char *name;//Name of the people who can sign in
};

void init_myStruct(struct sign_in *s_in) {
    s_in->name = calloc(1, sizeof(char)*1024);
    return;
}

void destroy_myStruct (struct sign_in *s_in) {
    free(s_in->name);
    s_in->name = NULL;
    return;
}

int get_name()
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *Fpointin = NULL;
    struct sign_in items[6];//array of six structure variables

    for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        init_myStruct(&items[i]);

    Fpointin =fopen("namepass.txt","r");
    if (Fpointin == NULL) {
        printf ("File does not exist.\n");
        goto end_of_use;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Here is the sign_in structure\n");//print the entirety of the sign_in structure
        for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            fscanf(Fpointin,"%s %d",items[i].name, &items[i].password);//read all values from the file into th structure
            printf("name: %s\ncode: %d\n\n", items[i].name, items[i].password);
        }
    }
    fclose(Fpointin);

end_of_use:
    for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        destroy_myStruct(&items[i]);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    get_name();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be really helpful to see what the structure sign_in looks like. But, from a quick look of the code, one obvious error is the way password is being scanned.

```
fscanf(Fpointin,"%s %d",items[i].name,items[i].password);
```

This line should be:

```
fscanf(Fpointin,"%s %d",items[i].name, &items[i].password);
```

You need to pass in the address of the variable items[i].password so that fscanf can store a value in the memory location pointed by that address.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `char name[];` in

```
struct sign_in
{
  ...
  char name[];
```

is of an incomplete type. It does not allocated memory.

Use

```
#define NAME_LEN_MAX 42

...

struct sign_in
{
  ...
  char name[NAME_LEN_MAX + 1];
```

for example and adjust the scanning like this:

```
fscanf(Fpointin, "%42s %d", items[i].name, &items[i].password);
```

Comment: Works Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be of type char *, and you you may not have allocated space for it.  It will then definitely crash

Comment: I don't think I have ever used type char*. Please explain?